# Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/recipes from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

None of the solutions proposed in other SO responses to similar questions have worked for my problem.

I have my react app running on `localhost:3000` and my server running on `localhost:3001` previously I was spinning up both things separately but I am now trying to use a `proxy` in my `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

This is throwing this error:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/recipes from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).
```

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors) aren't super helpful on this issue.

Here is my code:

```
RecipeList.jsx

export default function RecipeList() {
  const retrieveAllRecipes = function () {
    fetch('/api/recipes', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        console.log(json)
      })
  }

  retrieveAllRecipes()
```

```
routes.js

const express = require('express')
const db = require('./db')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/api/recipes', (req, res) => {
  db.readRecipes()
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      logError(err)
    })
})

function logError(err) {
  console.error('Uh oh!', err.message)
}

module.exports = {}
```

```
db.js

const config = require('./knexfile').development
const connection = require('knex')(config)

function readRecipes(db = connection) {
  return db('recipes').select()
}

module.exports = {
  readRecipes,
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, you understand that you still have to start the API separately? The proxy is only there to redirect `/api/recipes` to `localhost:3001`.

Comment: I see. When I start the server with ``npm start`` I get: 
``Something is already running on port 3000. [...] Would you like to run the app on another port instead? › (Y/n)``